# Удаление полей и передача get-параметров

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Имеется такой код:

```
<?php
$select_sql = "SELECT id, title, pages_title FROM ".$pages_table."";
$result = mysql_query($select_sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if(isset($_GET['del'])) { 
$query = "DELETE FROM ".$pages_table." WHERE `id` = '$id'";//Удаляем запись из БД
mysql_query($query);
}
do
{
$pages = $row['id'];
printf
("<tr class='tr'>
 <td id='p_num'>".$row['id']."</td>
<td class='num_title1'><b>%s</b></td>
<td class='num_title'>
<b>%s</b>
</td>
 <td class='num_title2'>
 <a href='?edit=".$row['id']."'>Редактировать</a><a href='?del=".$row['id']."'> Удалить</a>
</td>
</tr>",$row['title'], $row['pages_title']
);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

?>
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как сделать, чтобы он удалял выбранное поле или если нажата ссылка, эдит переходило на страницу edit.php с выбранным id.

Comment: **оффтоп** Давненько не встречал адептов Попова )) Чувствуется фирменный стиль.

Так добавьте в ссылку "Редактировать" путь к этой странице:

    <a href='edit.php?edit=".$row['id']."'>Редактировать</a>

Comment: А почему не удаляется?

Comment: @Shahin, судя по вашему коду, оно всё-таки может удаляться, но только вы этого не видите, т.к. сначала выбираете всё из БД, а только в следующем шаге, если $_GET['del'] присутствует, удаляете одну из записей.

Comment: Ну, может, покажите, как правильно надо, я так понимаю, айди не видно.

Comment: @Shahin, для начала, я бы отправил вас пройти курс реабилитации от видеоуроков Попова и иже с ним. К сожалению, на сегодняшний день [эта серия статей][1] уже слегка устарела, и не всё нужно из неё брать. Хотя почитать не помешает, если будете помнить, что для работы с БД сегодня не рекомендуется использовать расширение **mysql_***, а делать ставки на MySQLi или PDO. Вот тогда можно будет вернуться к этому разговору. 

   [1]:http://irbis-team.com/15/10/1